# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "80" at line 1, column 1100

Tags: java, javadb

I get the following exception,

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "80" at line 1, column 1100.
```

when I try to insert like the following!  Any idea what this could mean??!

```
String insertString = "insert into queries (data_id, query, "
                + "query_name, query_file_name, status) values(" + currentDataID + ", '"
                + params[1] + "', '" + params[2] + "', '" 
                + params[3] + "', '" + params[4] + "')";
try {
     Statement stmt = dbconn.createStatement();
     stmt.execute(insertString, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
     ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys(); 

     if (rs != null && rs.next()){     
           currentDataID = (int) rs.getLong(1); 
     } 
} catch (SQLException ex) {
}
```

Table definition,

```
CREATE TABLE queries (query_id INT not null primary key GENERATED "
                + "ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), data_id "
                + "INTEGER not null, foreign key (data_id) references data "
                + "(data_id), query LONG VARCHAR, query_name VARCHAR(150), "
                + "query_file_name VARCHAR(150),status VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: Don't build SQL queries like that, [use a `PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: I tried to but the RETUEN_GENERATED_KEYS function in JavaDB doesn't like it or either I have trouble implementing it!

Comment: log the `insertString` before executing it and see what happens

Comment: Your *params* don't happen to contain the character "'" unquoted, do they? Like in "was born in the '80s"...

Comment: Yes they do!  I see now what the problem is! How can I treat those in the lengthy query that might contains tens of them?!  Can you please show me how I can change this code to accomodate this fix!

Comment: ... which wouldn't be a problem if you used *PreparedStatements* as suggested by Philipp Reichard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this approach with a [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO queries (data_id, query, query_name," +
        " query_file_name, status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement stmt = dbconn.prepareStatement(insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
// Why do you set this if you want the DB to generate it?
stmt.setInt(1, currentDataID); // or setLong() depending on data type
stmt.setString(2, params[1]); // I assume params is a String[]
stmt.setString(3, params[2]);
stmt.setString(4, params[3]);
stmt.setString(5, params[4]);
stmt.execute();

ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
    // if it's an int, avoid the cast and use rs.getInt(1) instead
    currentDataID = (int) rs.getLong(1);
}
```

I don't understand why you set the `data_id` while the later code expects the database to generate it... Your table definition would help.

Comment: data_id is the foreign key which is referencing to another table called data.  The primary key is already generated in the making of the table!  Please view the question area to see the table definition!

Comment: Okay, I was just confused because you re-use `currentDataID` for both inserting the FK and then reading back the generated PK. You might want to use a new variable for clarity.

Comment: Fantastic!  I got two of my queries inserted but one is comming with this exception even though as you can see from the table definition the field is defined as "LONG VARCHAR",  java.sql.SQLDataException: A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR

Comment: If you're sure that it's actually the `LONG VARCHAR` column and not one of the `VARCHAR` columns (my guess) triggering that error, please open a new question with the exact query and especially parameter values that trigger that error. I really think it's more likely one of the `VARCHAR` columns `query_name`, `query_file_name` or `status`, though.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably happening because one of your `params[]` contains a quote character.

This problem is exactly why you shouldn't create SQL expressions like this, but should instead use a `PreparedStatement`. Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I tried but failed using PreparedStatement rather than this way!  Can you please show me how you would alter this to use PreparedStatement?!